# How do I disable the hyperlink in Power BI Text Boxes?

Tags: powerbi

If I add a Measure to a Text Box that simply calls the TODAY() function, the date becomes a hyperlink on the Report Tab.

How do I disable this hyperlink?  I simply want to show today's date.

The steps that I used to add a Measure to the text box are below.

1. In the Data Page, create a Measure named `Report Date = TODAY()`.
2. On the Visuals Page, click `Text box` in the `Insert` group of the `Home` tab of the ribbon bar.
3. Click `+ Value`
4. In the text box labeled `How would you calculate this value`, type `Report Date`.
5. Click `Save`.

The text box now shows todays date.  However, it is also a hyperlink with nowhere to go.

The only alternative is a Card or a Table.

- I was able to produce a nice business card by using a calculated column like:

  `CardText = [clientdescription] & UNICHAR(10) & [ServiceContactName] & UNICHAR(10) & [ServiceAddress1] & UNICHAR(10) & [ServiceCity] & ", " & [ServiceState] & " " & [ServiceZipCode]`

and set the Text box to `CardText`.

The `UNICHAR(10)` function embeds a line break in the `CardText` string.

This is nice because you can left-align the text (which you cannot do with a Card Visual).

This also updates when aligned with a Slicer.

However, the Text box shows the `CardText` as a hyperlink. There is no hyperlink address, and therefore, nothing to remove.

A text box that simply allows us to set text, alignment and all font properties (color, weight, font, size, italics, underline, bold, etc.) would be a godsend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the report is published, there will be no hyperlink behaviour on the date in the text box. The hyperlink behaviour is only present in Power BI desktop. Clicking on the hyperlink will open up the settings for the value, so you can edit them.

And you can totally control the font, size, color, etc of that text. Just select the date as it shows in the text box and use the formatting tools. Like with Constantia font in 16 pt and pink.
[image]

If you don't want the hyperlink behaviour, consider using the measure in the Title of the text box instead of the body. You can also add the measure to the title of any other visual. To do that, you first need a measure that returns text, since the Title of a visual cannot show dates.

```
ReportDateText = format(TODAY(),"dddd, dd MMM YYYY")
```

Now you can edit the title property of a visual.

1. Turn the title on
2. Click the formula button to open the dialog
3. Select the measure with the text version of the date
4. The result shows in the visual's title.

[image]